# Parse.com PFQueryTableViewController with Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm trying to get PFQueryTableViewController setup with a Storyboard and I'm following [this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/geolocations), specifically section 2. Everything works when I use the initWithStyle method but when I try the Storyboard method I get: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: classname)'.

Here's my MasterViewController.h:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface MasterViewController : PFQueryTableViewController

@end
```

Here's a shot of my Identity Inspector:

[image: Identity Inspector]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. The problem was that the Xcode cache was pulling from older projects with the same name. Clearing the cache solved all of my problems.